# Adding elements from one array to another Java

Tags: java, arrays

Just coming back to Java after a few years break. I am trying to  select elements from one array and store them in another in Java. I have created a new array of the same type with a fixed number of elements. The array that I am copying from is not null I have printed it out. But when I try to display the new array the values are not there - just a reference to the element. There probably something that I have overlooked. I have been searching for the last day but am not getting anywhere. I would really appreciate some help. Code below:

```
PersonDetails user = new PersonDetails(userName,userGender,userAge,userInterests);
PersonDetails [] userArray =  new PersonDetails [numberOfDaters];   
PersonDetails [] dateArray =  new PersonDetails [numberOfDaters];   
userArray = user.getArray("datingdata.txt", numberOfDaters);
dateArray = Arrays.copyOf(userArray, userArray.length);

char [][] interestArray = new char[numberOfDaters][5];  
for (int z =0;z<userArray.length; z++) {                
   interestArray[z] =
      userArray[z].getAllInterests( userArray[z].getInterests());                   
}
String remove = user.getOnes(interestArray);
System.out.print(remove);
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(remove); 
int num = st.countTokens();
PersonDetails [] userRemoveArray =  new PersonDetails [num]; 
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
   int token = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
   for(int x =0;x<userRemoveArray.length;x++) {
      userRemoveArray[x] = userArray[token];
   }
   System.out.println(userRemoveArray);  
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
[LPersonDetails;@a8c488
[LPersonDetails;@a8c488
[LPersonDetails;@a8c488
[LPersonDetails;@a8c488
[LPersonDetails;@a8c488
[LPersonDetails;@a8c488
[LPersonDetails;@a8c488
[LPersonDetails;@a8c488
[LPersonDetails;@a8c488
[LPersonDetails;@a8c488
[LPersonDetails;@a8c488
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to sse `Arrays.toString` when printing arrays.

Comment: Hi Beth,you need to override the toString() method of your PersonDetails  class. That will do the trick for you. By default it will print the reference pointer address which signifies the location. You need to override the toString() method and tell how you want your PersonDetails class variables to be displayed. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Beth There's a `System.out.printf` why did you come back?

Comment: Was not well for a while better now Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.addAll(...)` method or one of the many methods found [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=3).

As for printing out the elements of the array... you will have to implement your own `.toString()` method to avoid displaying the object reference.

Comment: Just want thank everyone for their helpful comments had a printf method in my class and that worked I appreciate you taking time to answer my question BAM

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example to make it more easier for you since you had noted that you are just coming back to Java after sometime and i hope this helps you out :)

```
public class PersonDetails {

private String userName;

private String gender;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PersonDetails [userName=" + userName + ", gender=" + gender
            + "]";
}

}
```

Now when you print out the Array, the String created within the toString() method will print for each PersonDetail object.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(userRemoveArray));`.
or

```
for(int i = 0; i < userRemoveArray.length;i++) {
  System.out.print(userRemoveArray[i]+", ");
}
System.out.println();
```